# Передача переменной из receiver'a в другой класс

Tags: java, android

Есть broadcast receiver, нужно из него передать String number в обычный класс MainActivity. Как это сделать?

Код broadcast'a:

```
public class PhoneStateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        }
    }

}
```